# Digital Ocean returning bad URL for images bigger than 5 MB

Tags: digital-ocean-spaces

I am using digital ocean for storing images. It was all working fine till I was using Firebase. I moved to MongoDB and Node js server.
Now I am uploading images and when its more than 5 MBs, I get URL which is missing https:// and also  appears somewhere in between the URL.

I was expecting
https://my-bucket.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/folderName/image_picker_44B4654D-A164-41A8-B86E-4844B3699137-88682-00002E3606926DB8.jpg
And I am getting
nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/my-bucket/folderName/image_picker_44B4654D-A164-41A8-B86E-4844B3699137-88682-00002E3606926DB8.jpg

My code snippet is

```
const file = req.files.image;
const businessId = req.body.businessId;
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(req.files.image.filepath);
const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com');
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
  region: 'nyc3',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu',
    secretAccessKey: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
  },
});

s3.upload(
  {
    Bucket: 'dummy-spaces', // Add bucket name here
    ACL: 'public-read', // Specify whether anyone with link can access the file
    Key: `businessPhotosOfWork/${file.originalFilename}`, // Specify folder and file name
    Body: buffer,
  },
  {},
).send((err: AWSError | null, data: any) => {
  console.log(`${err}`);
  if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: `${err}` });

  // Unlink file
  fs.unlinkSync(file.filepath);

  return successResponse(res, 'Operation Successful', { url: data.Location });
  // Return file url or other necessary details
});
```

},

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Tarun, have you checked the access policies on bucket/storage?

Comment: @Pragyan I am doing this as patch to repair the broken string coming from DigitalOcean. 
function ensureHttps(url) {
  if (!url.startsWith('https://')) {
    url = 'https://abc-spaces.' + url;
  }
  return url;
}
function removeSubstring(originalString, substringToRemove) {
  return originalString.replace(substringToRemove, '');
}
url = removeSubstring(url, "abc-spaces/");